# GlusterFS PVC mount error on IBM Cloud Private 3.1 (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, glusterfs, ibm-cloud-private

I am getting following error when app is trying to mount GlusterFS volume based PVC on IBM Cloud Private 3.1. Strangely, I am able to mount GlusterFS volumes without any issues via command line `mount -t glusterfs IP-ADDRESS-OR-HOST-NAME:vol10 /testmntfolder/vol10`

**Error Message**

> the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to
> help diagnose this issue:
>
> [2018-10-16 01:03:13.584657] E [MSGID:
> 101075] [common-utils.c:319:gf_resolve_ip6] 0-resolver: getaddrinfo
> failed (Name or service not known)
>
> The message "E [MSGID: 101046]
> [dht-common.c:1501:dht_lookup_dir_cbk] 0-vol10-dht: dict is null"
> repeated 3 times between [2018-10-16 01:03:13.589303] and [2018-10-16
> 01:03:13.595994]

Comment: Can you post your PV and PVC definitions in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

From the errors, seems the issue is caused by the 'Name or service not known'. Please check:

1. The hosts files are same in all the ICP nodes.
2. On each ICP node, ensure it can resolve the other ICP node by hostname and IP.